# Given that $T \sim \text{exp}(\lambda)$, then $P(T \leq t + \Delta t | T \gt t) \approx \lambda \Delta t$.

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, exponential-function, exponential-distribution

I am reading a book titled [Probability and Random Processes for Computer and Electrical Engineers](https://edisciplinas.usp.br/mod/resource/view.php?id=3131969) and I came across a small tidbit which seems easy but I had a hard time showing why it was true. From page 140...

Given that $T \sim \text{exp}(\lambda)$, then $P(T \leq t + \Delta t | T \gt t) \approx \lambda \Delta t$. Now this seems like it should be easy to show so I just worked out the integral and I can't explain exactly why it is true...

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_x^{x + \Delta x} &= \lambda e^{-\lambda t}  dx\\
&= \Big[ -e^{-\lambda x} \Big]^{t + \Delta t}_t  \\
&= -e^{-\lambda(t + \Delta t)} (-) - e^{-\lambda(t)} \\
&= -e^{-\lambda t} e^{-\lambda \Delta t} + e^{-\lambda t} \\
&= e^{-\lambda t} (1 - e^{-\lambda \Delta t}) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

but I cannot see how this should reduce to just $\lambda \Delta t$. Seems like I am missing something simple but I cannot see it. Have I setup the problem completely wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your caclulation seems a little messy... I won't point out all the mistakes you have made. I believe that my answer below will make things clear.

By definition,
$$P(T\leq t+\Delta t|T>t)=\frac{P(t<T\leq t+\Delta t)}{P(T>t)},$$
so
\begin{align*}
P(T\leq t+\Delta t|T>t)&=\frac{\int_t^{t+\Delta t}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx}{\int_t^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx}\\
&=\frac{-e^{-\lambda x}|_t^{t+\Delta t}}{-e^{-\lambda x}|_t^{\infty}}\\
&=\frac{e^{-\lambda t}-e^{-\lambda (t+\Delta t)}}{e^{-\lambda t}}\\
&=1-e^{-\lambda\Delta t}.
\end{align*}
Recall that $e^x\sim x+1$ for $x\to0$, so we have
$$P(T\leq t+\Delta t|T>t)=1-e^{-\lambda\Delta t}\approx 1-(-\lambda\Delta t+1)=\lambda \Delta t,$$
here we consider $\Delta t$ very small.

Comment: Thanks. I made an error in transcribing which I fixed.

Comment: @Joff Good. Also, you wrote $-e^{-\lambda t} e^{-\lambda \Delta t} + e^{-\lambda t} = -e^{-\lambda t} (e^{-\lambda \Delta t} + 1)$, which should be $-e^{-\lambda t} (e^{-\lambda \Delta t} -1)$